# Highlight lines in a PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, blob

A program searches for a particular record in a database which has a `BLOB` field containing a PDF in it. I need to output the file to the user using Java Servlets.

This was easy, but now I need to search for specific words/lines and highlight them and then output the PDF file with the highlighted text.

I am using a Oracle 10g database.

Is iText an option for doing this?

Comment: When using iText you should be aware that from version 5 you have to buy a licence for commercial-use.  Just a warning.

Comment: @tom hope I dont need that if I use itext 2.1.7...